# Is there a standard way to relativize algorithmic complexity constructively?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

Given an index set $A$ of indices that compute some (class of) structures such that $A$ is complete in the class $ \Pi^0_n$ in the arithmetical hierarchy, let’s say we want to determine the algorithmic complexity of some index set $B$ of indices that compute some (class of) structures *within the class we get from* $A$. Let’s say that we could somehow determine that, absolutely, this algorithmic complexity for $B$, assuming structures from $A$ as our “domain of discourse” were $\Pi^0_m$ complete themselves.

Is there some meaningful way we can relate these two complexities so as to remain within the more general class $A$ and work “relative to $A$”? Maybe something like $\Pi^{\overline{\textbf{0}^{(m)}}}_n$ ?

Comment: Please don't use LaTeX/MathJax to add emphasis to text. That's what [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) is for.

Comment: Thanks, now I can format more _germanely_.

Comment: Why is the word "constructively" in the title? To lure constructivists into classical mathematics? But more seriously: what does "compute structures" mean, and what does it mean to compute structures "within a class we get from $A$". I find the question confusing.

Comment: I will admit it is partially done to lure, but it is somewhat intended to suggest a “building upon previous work” taste that is not evident in usual computability (AFAIK). Also we don’t use choice so it’s not really all that classical, in my defense, although I guess LEM is present. “Compute structures” means that an index in the set is that of the $e^{th}$ program that computes the atomic diagram of a structure. This, I think, is fairly standard in the theory of computable models. And the last question is more or less “restriction” to the indices of $A$, but I am open to suggestions.

Comment: To clarify further, I say I’m “open to suggestions” because your last question is, in some sense, a refinement of my own question. How can we make sense of “computing structures relative to some class of structures”, assuming there is some “compatibility” of how these things are generated. Can it be done? It may be an elementary question, but I can’t seem to find a satisfactory answer in the literature. Otherwise, if some examples are in order I could probably conjure them.